# tablesorter with two header rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am using the [tablesorter jquery plugin](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) and my table has two rows in the header. Is there any way to enable sorting on my table? it should be able to be sortable by the second header row the first header row is just there to group related data by a date. If this is not possible using this plugin maybe someone has a suggestion for a workaround?

Here is an example of my table markup

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">January</th>
      <th colspan="3">February</th>
      <th colspan="3">March</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- January -->
      <th>Metric 1</th>
      <th>Metric 2</th>
      <th>Metric 3</th>
      <!-- February -->
      <th>Metric 1</th>
      <th>Metric 2</th>
      <th>Metric 3</th>
      <!-- March -->
      <th>Metric 1</th>
      <th>Metric 2</th>
      <th>Metric 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- January -->
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <!-- February -->
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <!-- March -->
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <!-- etc -->
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All you had to do was try ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/402/

If you want the top row disabled, then add a `sorter-false` class to those header cells:

```
<tr>
  <th class="sorter-false" colspan="3">January</th>
  <th class="sorter-false" colspan="3">February</th>
  <th class="sorter-false" colspan="3">March</th>
</tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/403/

Comment: Thanks.Can you also tell when you have sorter-false still onclick you see the blue border.Is there a way to not show it in the plugin.

Comment: Hmm, I think you mean the focus outline... if that is the case, I'll fix it in the next update, in the mean time, use the `initialized` callback to remove the `tabindex` on those cells `initialized: function( table ) { $( table ).find('.sorter-false').removeAttr( 'tabindex' ); }` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/5284/)).

Comment: What is the `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` needed for? Your example works even if I remove it...

Comment: @Emaborsa If you look at the [Widgets](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#extras) section of the docs, you'll see `† these widgets are included in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file (except for extra filter formatter functions).` Essentially, it's some of the commonly used widgets: Column highlighter, Filter, Resizable columns, Save sort, sticky headers, uitheme and storage widgets. You can also follow [these instructions](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Customize) to customize what widgets are included in the file.