# Odd tablesorter behavior when using two header rows and sortlist

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

When there are two rows in a table head, and only the lower one should be available for sorting, then this can be achieved by applying `class="sorter-false"` to the cells in the first row. However, when `data-sortlist` is used for the same table to accomplish an initial sorting, then there is an odd side effect: When the header of the sorted column is clicked for the first time, nothing happens (the expected behavior would be to reverse the sorting). Is there a solution for this?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N9TLf/

Code:

```
<table data-sortlist="[[0,0]]">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorter-false" colspan="2">January</th>
      <th class="sorter-false" colspan="2">February</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- January -->
      <th>Metric 1</th>
      <th>Metric 2</th>
      <!-- February -->
      <th>Metric 1</th>
      <th>Metric 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- January -->
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <!-- February -->
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- January -->
      <td>Value 1c</td>
      <td>Value 2b</td>
      <!-- February -->
      <td>Value 1a</td>
      <td>Value 2b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- January -->
      <td>Value 1a</td>
      <td>Value 2c</td>
      <!-- February -->
      <td>Value 1c</td>
      <td>Value 2a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- January -->
      <td>Value 1b</td>
      <td>Value 2a</td>
      <!-- February -->
      <td>Value 1b</td>
      <td>Value 2c</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
  </tbody>
<table>
```

(Code and JSFiddle adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823951/tablesorter-with-two-header-rows))

Comment: Hey, that looks like a bug! I'll have it fixed in the next update.

Comment: If you need it sooner, it's available in the working branch of the github repository; [here is the actual fix](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/commit/320b1f1b291e66eafabf55dee05e7f55cab9b5a7)

Comment: @Mottie: That was fast, and it's working! Thank you very much!

Comment: v2.16.3 is now available with this fix. Thanks again!