# Multi-row header in tablesorter: How to prevent top row from sorting?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using [Mottie's fork of the jQuery tablesorter plugin](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter). My question is related to a similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823951/tablesorter-with-two-header-rows) but I don't want my top-most row to sort the table. I tried adding `class="sorter-false"` to my  tag.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t0tka1gx/4/

Note that the top row of the header has a sort arrow. Clicking the pager arrows causes the table to be sorted.

How to prevent the top row of the header from behaving this way?

Answer (score 1):

In your first header cell there are 2 class attributes(`<td class="pager" colspan="5" class="sorter-false">`) that is why it is not working

```
<td class="pager sorter-false" colspan="5">
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n0mocuz1/)

Comment: DOH! Good catch. Thanks!